# How to return an array fibonaci numbers in C #?

Tags: c#

I want to make a function that takes an array of integers as input and print  an array of int as Fibonaci series like: third element= second element + first element.

Here is my code so far:

```
static void  Result(int[] arr)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("arr[i]", arr[i], "  number to get must be greater or equal than 0");

        var n = arr[i] + 1; 
        var a = new int[n];
        arr[0] = 0;

        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            a[1] = 1;
        }
        for ( i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];
        }                
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    int[] arr = {7, 8, 3, 9, 11,16,14,91, }; 
    Result(arr);
}
```

Comment: please explain what exactly the _problem_ is you've encountered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I do fibonaci sequence under 1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210928/how-i-do-fibonaci-sequence-under-1000)

Comment: What is the purpose of the input array? Fibonacci starts with 1 & 1.

Comment: it is helpful for us if you would use the following structure: 1) This is the output that I expect and 2) this is the output I get. Problem: they don't match in the following way:... something along these line. Could you please post it

Comment: You may want to give an example input and the expected output.

Comment: Please specify the expected output.

Comment: I am taking an array of integers of input. I wan to display an array of integers that match the condition  like in fibonaci series where third number = sec number + firstnumber ... fourth number= third+ second... I want to print those numbers in this array that match this condition.

Comment: @Dev999 What should the output look like for your array? Specify what the output is. An example

Comment: Is this: `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 22, 30, 39` what you expect with the input `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9`,?

Comment: so you basically want to pick out the fibonaci series from the input array. Did I understood correctly ? and the input array does not start always from 1 ?=! If it does not start from 1 you would need to calculate the entire series from scratch, because you cannot know whether the first number in the array belongs to the series

Comment: You have a `for (int i = 0; ...` and inside of that another `for ( i = 2;...` - this changes the `i` value as used by the outer loop

Comment: The only "print" you do is an error message, and then you continue processing anyway.

Comment: Change the return type from void to int[] : static int[]  Result(int[] arr)

Comment: basically you would need a `List<int>` in which you would collect the matches. Then you need to create the fibonaci series from scratch running until the highest number in your array. and after the creation of each number you need to check whether a match with this number exists in the array, if so then collect. In the end you need to return the list, so change the return type as jdweng suggested.

Comment: if input is  1 ,3 ,6, 7 ,8 10, 11, 15 ,25 output should be  4, 9, 15 so 1+3=4, 3+6=9 and so on..

Comment: @DekuDesu sorry for the confusion , if input is 1 ,3 ,6, 7 ,8 10, 11, 15 ,25 output should be 4, 9, 15 so 1+3=4, 3+6=9 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

> if input is : 1 ,3 ,4 ,6, 7 ,8 10, 11, 15 ,25 output should be: 1, 3, 4, 7, 11 so 1+3=4, 4+3=7 and so on.

I took a look at your code and you were very close.

The biggest issue was you were starting at `i = 0` which would cause errors if you attempted to access `arr[-1]` and `arr[-2]`.

We can solve that by starting with `i = 2`.

For example:

```cs
static int[] Result(int[] arr)
{    
    int[] result = arr;

    for (int i = 2; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = result[i-1] + result[i-2];
    }

    return result;
}

int[] arr = { 1 ,3 ,4 ,6, 7 ,8, 10, 11, 15 ,25 };

arr = Result(arr);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",arr));
// outputs: 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123
```

Another side note is that unless you're passing the `int[] arr` as a reference you will need to return a new `int[]` as the result since `Result()`'s changes to `arr` are not reflected on the array.